# Group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_3[[x]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-adic-number-theory, formal-power-series

I am trying to calculate the group of units of the power series ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[[x]]$. I know that all the unit elements are of the form $u+\sum_1^{\infty} a_nx^n$ where $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, where $\mathbb{Z}_3$ are the $3$-adic integers. However I am not sure about the group structure.

For example, we have many subgroups $U_i$ which are the set of elements of the form $u+\sum_i^{\infty} a_nx^n$ i.e the power series where the first power of $x$ is $x^i$. These groups form a filtration on the group of units. Is there a way to relate these groups to the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_3[[x]]$ similar to the result for the ring $\mathbb{F}_3[[x]]$? For the result for $\mathbb{F}_3[[x]]$ look at Thm 4.4 [here](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eura-reports/063/McMurdie.Christopher/Final.pdf).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{F}_3$ precisely $\mathbb{Z}_3$? Finite fields are uniquely determined by their cardinality.

Comment: Unless you mean the $3$-adic integers, of course.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I mean the 3-adics

Comment: For perspective, the ring of power series over $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p[[x]]$ is *the* classical example of an *Iwasawa Algebra* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_algebra) a.k.a. completed group ring, and has been studied extensively. As for the structure of the unit group, indeed the idea of a filtration (studied already by Lazard) should be most helpful here. Of course, unlike in the case of $\mathbb F_p$-coefficients (where the ring is just a DVR), now we have to take $p$-powers into account too, as Lazard and others did.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks for the comment! Do you have any references which talk about the units using a filtration? Thanks in advance

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_3[[x]]^\times = \Bbb{Z}_3^\times \times \prod_{n\ge 1} (1+x^n)^{\Bbb{Z}_3}$

Comment: @reuns This is the sort of thing I was looking for! Do you have any reference for this or a simple proof of this fact?

Comment: @reuns I would also be interested  in knowing if there is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_3[[x]]^{\times} = \mathbb{Z}_3^{\times} \times \Pi_{n \geq 1} P_n(x)^{\mathbb{Z}_3}$ where $P_n(x)$ are power series with the lowest degree term (apart from 1) being $ux^n$ where $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Comment: @reuns Now that I think about it, the "general isomorphism" I was looking for follows from the fact you mentioned by just changing basis which is a upper triangular matrix right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For $n\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$, the map $$a\mapsto (1+x^n)^a=\sum_{k\ge 0} x^{nk} {a\choose k},\qquad\Bbb{Z}_3\to\Bbb{Z}_3[[x]]^\times$$ is well-defined as $a\mapsto {a\choose k},\Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}\to \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ is an integer valued polynomial which is thus 3-adically continuous.
- If $f=1+ax^n+O(x^{n+1})$ then $f= (1+x^n)^a g$ with $g=1+O(x^{n+1})$,
- Whence for $h\in \Bbb{Z}_3[[x]]^\times$ there is a unique $u\in \Bbb{Z}_3^\times$ and a unique sequence $a_n$ such that $$h=u\prod_{n\ge 1} (1+x^n)^{a_n}$$
- Where the convergence is in the topology on $\Bbb{Z}_3[[x]]^\times$ inherited from the discrete valuation on $\Bbb{Q}_3[[x]]$. With the product topology on $\Bbb{Z}_3^\times \times \prod_{n\ge 1} (1+x^n)^{\Bbb{Z}_3}$ we get that as topological groups
  $$\Bbb{Z}_3[[x]]^\times = \Bbb{Z}_3^\times \times \prod_{n\ge 1} (1+x^n)^{\Bbb{Z}_3}$$
  Of course we can replace $1+x^n$ by $1+u_n x^n+ r_n x^{n+1} $ for any sequence of $u_n\in \Bbb{Z}_3^\times,r_n\in \Bbb{Z}_3[[x]]$.

Comment: very nice - but for completeness, can you give a specific reference?